# How to listen on IP and Port in Java ? with ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, serversocket

I'm creating a client/server chat (Multi-threading) app in Java .

I want to listen to clients on a specific port and IP .

When I do this :

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept connection

// more code
```

**Does it mean that the IP that I'm listening is `127.0.0.1` ? i.e. `localhost` ?**

From a look on the constructor of ServerSocket object , we have 3 types of constructors :

```
public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog) throws IOException
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)  throws IOException
```

What constructor should I use , if I want to get clients from **OTHER** IP addresses

This one :

```
public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
```

Or this one :

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)  throws IOException
```

?

Much appreciated

Comment: @fge: When I use the 1st one , Does it mean that the IP that I'm listening is 127.0.0.1 ? i.e. localhost ?

Comment: Uhm no, sorry, I was mistaken; the first two forms will bind to 0.0.0.0 and ::0; that is _all_ local interfaces, including 127.0.0.1. So you should REALLY use the third form.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that the IP that I'm listening is 127.0.0.1 ? i.e. localhost ?

No. It means you are listening on all IP addresses of  your host.

> What constructor should I use if I want to get clients from other IP addresses?

This one.

Answer (score -1):

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
int port =8081;
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port,5,inetAddress);
```

Do you mean this？May it will helpful.
And the second arguement means - requested maximum length of the queue of incoming connections(from jdc).

Comment: He wants to get clients from other IP addresses. Plural. You've misread the question.